# Search box looks different on mobile, cannot get it to be in the center of the page nor reduce the size of the search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My site looks different on mobile, the hotel search box does not show up in it's entirety, so the labels at the bottom get cut off. Also I tried to add the following CSS code, it helped to center the hotel search box but I cannot get it to move the box closer to the header and make it smaller so that when I click on options they are not cut off:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .containerBox {
     width: 100%!important;
    }
}
```

Here is the link and screenshot of what I am talking about. 
[Hotel Search box on the home page.](https://vacacionan2.com/)

I will include the full code below.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    #selectCountry:ACTIVE, #destino:ACTIVE, #selectCountry:FOCUS, #destino:FOCUS {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #ed8323; }

    .select-complementarias {
      border: 0px solid #dadada !important;
      border-radius: 3px !important;
      padding: 5px !important;
      font-weight: bold !important;
      color: #424547 !important;
      width: 100%; }

    .select-complementarias:ACTIVE, .select-complementarias:FOCUS {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #ed8323; }

    .searchCity {
      min-width: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      color: #424547; }

    .warning {
      color: #FF0000 !important;
      font-size: 14px; }

    .numInputHidden, .elementHidden {
      display: none; }

    .divNewLine {
      clear: left;
      padding: 3px; }

    .divCell {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      max-width: 236px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .cell-complementarias {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 250px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px; }

    .divCell-auto {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .divCellSmall {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 110px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .divCell-20px {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .divCell-50px {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 50px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .divCell-130px {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 130px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .divCell-100px {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2px;
      width: 100px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 3px; }

    .time-hours {
      width: 100px !important; }

    .time-minutes {
      width: 100px !important; }

    .hoursFligths {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 11px;
      width: 130px !important; }

    #selectsMenores select {
      width: 50px; }

    .textHidden {
      display: none; }

    .ui-datepicker {
      font-size: 11px; }

    .ui-widget {
      font-size: 12px; }

    .containerBox input {
      border: 0px solid #dadada;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 5px;
      /*font-weight: bold;*/
      line-height:21px!important;
      width: 95%!important;
      }
    .containerBox select {
      border: 0px solid #dadada !important;
      border-radius: 3px !important;
      padding: 5px !important;
      /*font-weight: bold !important;*/
      color: #424547 !important;
      width: 100%;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      cursor: pointer;
        height:auto;
      }

    #selectCountry {
      width: 95% !important; }

    .input-date {
      width: 100%;
      color: #424547; }

    .input-date-home {
      width: 357px !important;
      color: #424547; }

    .input-date:ACTIVE, .input-date-home:FOCUS, .input-date-home:ACTIVE, .input-date-home:FOCUS {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #ed8323; }

    .ui-widget {
      font-weight: bold !important; }

    .ui-widget-content {
      font-weight: bold !important;
      border: 0px solid #eee; }

    .container-box-ticket, .container-box-hotel {
      width: 375px !important; }

    .container-box-ticket {
      width: 375px !important; }

    .containerBox {
      font-family: arial;
      border: 0px solid #dadada;
      width: 512px!important;
      background-color: #262626e8;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 17px;
      /*font-weight: bold;*/
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative; }
      .containerBox label {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        }
      .containerBox input:FOCUS {
        border: 0px solid #dadada;
        border-color: #53a69d;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;
        background-color: #ed8323;
        color: #FFFFFF; }

    select:FOCUS, .containerBox input:ACTIVE, select:ACTIVE {
      border: 0px solid #dadada !important;
      border-color: #ed8323 !important;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000 !important;
      background-color: #ed8323 !important;
      color: #FFFFFF !important; }

    .containerBox button {
      border: 0px solid #D8D8D8;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #F2F2F2;
      font: arial;
      font-size: 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100px;
      height: 35px!important; }
      .containerBox button:HOVER {
        border-radius: 3px;
        border-color: #CED8F6;
        background-color: #D8D8D8; }

    #divbuttonverpreciosbuscando {
      display: none; }

    .spinner {
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px!important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px; }
      .spinner > div {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 100%!important;
        width: 6px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
        animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out; }
      .spinner .rect2 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
        animation-delay: -1.1s; }
      .spinner .rect3 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
        animation-delay: -1s; }
      .spinner .rect4 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
        animation-delay: -0.9s; }
      .spinner .rect5 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
        animation-delay: -0.8s; }

    @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
      0%, 40%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4); }
      20% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); } }
    @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
      0%, 40%, 100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.4);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4); }
      20% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); } }
    hr {
      color: #ed8323;
      border-color: #ed8323; }

    .titulo {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px; }

    .titulo-segundo {
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-left: -8px;
      margin-right: 38px;
      margin-top: -28px;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: left;
      width: 225px;
      z-index: 110; }

    #ver_precios, .buttonForm {
      background-color: #ed8323 !important;
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
      font-weight: bold !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      border: 0 solid #d8d8d8;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 35px;!important; }

    .ui-datepicker {
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      color: #EEE;
      border: 0px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000; }

    .ui-datepicker-header {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      background: #ffffff !important;
      border: 0px !important; }

    .ui-widget-header {
      background: #ffffff !important; }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold !important;
      background: #262626; }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-button {
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
      font-size: 16px !important;
      font-weight: bold !important;
      background: #262626 !important; }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-state-focus {
      background: red; }

    .ui-dialog {
      background: #262626;
      position: fixed; }

    .ui-datepicker-title {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 1em !important; }

    .ui-datepicker-month {
      color: #ed8323;
      padding: 0px !important;
      margin: 0px !important;
      background-color: #ffffff; }

    .ui-datepicker-year {
      color: #ed8323;
      background-color: #ffffff; }

    .ui-datepicker .ui-state-default {
      background: #ffffff !important;
      border: 0px solid #d3d3d3 !important; }

    .ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
      color: #000000 !important;
      text-align: center; }

    .ui-state-active {
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      background: #ed8323 !important;
      cursor: pointer !important;
      text-decoration: none !important; }

    .ui-state-focus {
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      cursor: pointer !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      border: 0px; }

    .ui-state-focus:HOVER {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
      background: #1ec7e6 !important; }

    .ui-menu, .ui-menu-item {
      background: #ed8323 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }

    .ui-datepicker-calendar td a.ui-state-hover {
      background: #ed8323 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }

    .ui-datepicker-calendar td a.ui-state-active {
      background: #ed8323 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }

    .ui-datepicker-calendar td a.ui-state-focus {
      background: #ed8323 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important; }

    .ui-datepicker-title {
      margin: 0 2.3em;
      text-align: center; }

    .ui-datepicker-year {
      display: block;
      font-size: 9px;
      margin-left: -5px; }

    .ui-datepicker table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      font-size: 0.9em; }

    .calendarioIcon {
      height: 19px!important;
      margin: 6px 149px;
      position: absolute; }

    .close-dialog-icon {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 51px;
      margin: -22px 525px 0;
      position: absolute; }

    .calendarioIcon-hotel {
      height: 19px!important;
      margin: 3px 20px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 5%; }

    .calendarioIcon-tickets {
      height: 19px!important;
      margin: 6px 438px;
      position: absolute; }

    .calendario-icon-homes {
      height: 19px!important;
      margin: 3px 440px;
      position: absolute; }

    .calendario-icon-arrow {
      height: 25px!important;
      margin: 3px 175px;
      position: absolute; }

    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
      background: white url("material/ring-alt.svg") right center no-repeat;
      background-size: 20px 20px; }

    .spinner {
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px; }
      .spinner > div {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 100%;
        width: 6px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
        animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out; }
      .spinner .rect2 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
        animation-delay: -1.1s; }
      .spinner .rect3 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
        animation-delay: -1s; }
      .spinner .rect4 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
        animation-delay: -0.9s; }
      .spinner .rect5 {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
        animation-delay: -0.8s; }

    @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
      0%, 40%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4); }
      20% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); } }
    @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
      0%, 40%, 100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.4);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4); }
      20% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); } }
    #divbuttonverpreciosbuscando {
      display: none; }

    .ui-corner-all {
      border: 0px; }

    #airline {
      width: 100%!important; }

    .label-hiden {
      display: none !important; }

    .containerBox-header {
      opacity: 0.9 !important;
     /* border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;*/ }

    .containerBox-footer {
      opacity: 1 !important;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
     /* padding-top: 9px !important;
      padding-bottom: 20px !important;*/
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      transition-property: background;
     /* height: 5px !important;*/
      background-color: #ed8323 !important;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500 !important; }

    .containerBox-footer:HOVER {
      background-color: #ed8323 !important;
      cursor: pointer; }

    .buscar-label {
      margin-top: 5px !important; }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar, .ui-dialog label {
      background: #262626 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
      color: #FFFFFF; }

    .error-input {
      border-color: #FF0000;
      box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
      background-color: #FBEFF2; }

    .error-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: red !important; }

    .error-input::-moz-placeholder {
      color: red !important; }

    .error-input:-moz-placeholder {
      color: red !important; }

    .error-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: red !important; }

    .containerBox input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #000000; }
    .containerBox input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #000000; }
    .containerBox input::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #000000; }
    .containerBox input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #000000 !important; }
    .containerBox input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #000000 !important; }
    .containerBox input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #000000 !important; }

    #not-found-sources {
      color: #FFFFFF; }

    .ui-autocomplete-input .ui-corner-all {
      color: #000000 !important; }

    .ui-autocomplete a {
      color: #000000 !important; }
    .box_float{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 90px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    li{
        list-style-type: none!important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .caja_fondo{
        height:auto;
        font-family: arial;
        border: 0px solid #dadada;
        opacity: 0.8;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 17px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        padding: 15px;
        position: relative; 
    }  
    .catalog-area {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: rgba(39,46,59,.8);
        height: auto;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }

    /*.imagenes_circuitos {
        height: 456px;
        width: 370px;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .imagenes_circuitos_min{
        padding-top: 20px;*/
    }
    .circuit_catalog {
        display: table-cell;
        z-index: 9;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: gray;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .circuit_catalog a {
        color: #3c5c8b;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 12px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: gray;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    /*.img_circuits {
        opacity: .8;
        width: 160px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3C5C8B;*/
    }
    .containerBoxCircuits {
        font-family: arial;
        border: 0px solid #dadada;
        background-color: #262626;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 17px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        opacity: .8;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    .container-box-circuit{
        margin-left:20px;
        display:none;
    }

    /*.img_circuits_min {
        width: 80px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3C5C8B;*/
    }
    .circuit_catalog_min {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 12px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        width: 88px;
        height: 110px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: gray;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
        transition-property: box-shadow;
    }

    .celdas {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    .containerBox-circuits {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*.img_circuits_botmin {
        background-color: #d42729;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 10px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 23px;
        line-height: 10px;
        font-size: 7px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: inherit;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;*/
    }
    .textcatmin {
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 22px;
        line-height: 7px;
        font-size: 7px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: inherit;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .containerBoxAll {
        width: 512px!important;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; 
    }
    .tab-content .tab-menu button {
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        padding-top: 15px !important;
        padding-bottom: 15px !important;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-property: background;
        height: 5px !important;
        background-color: #ed8323 !important;
        width: 81px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .tab-content .tab-menu button:HOVER {
      background-color: #ed8323 !important;
      cursor: pointer; 
      color:#000;
    }

    .tab-content .tab-menu button.active {
        background-color: #262626!important;
        color: #ed8323 ;
    }
    span.titulo-tabs {
        word-wrap:normal;
        float:left;
        line-height: 0px;
    }
    .footerAll {
        width: 512px!important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;     
    }
    .form-service{
        margin-left: 13px;
        margin-right: -13px;
    }
    .CircuitsAll { 
        width: 511px!important;
        opacity: 1!important;
    }
    .CircuitsAll:HOVER  { 
        opacity: 1!important;
    }
    .containerBoxCircuitsAll:HOVER {
        opacity: 1!important;
    }
    .containerBoxCircuitsAll{
        width: 541px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    }
    .tab-content{
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }
    input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        width: 15px!important;
    }
    /*# sourceMappingURL=comun.css.map */
```

Comment: Also, there's an issue with how the search box on the Orders page appears (Mis Reservas) [link] (https://vacacionan2.com/mis-reservas/). It shows up properly on mobile but you can see the full search box because it's too long.

Comment: You mean the box which appears here - https://vacacionan2.com/hoteles/ ??

Comment: @DhavalJardosh yes that one and the one on this page (https://vacacionan2.com/mis-reservas/) - the CSS looks weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use these css

```
  @media(max-width:767px){
    .html_header_transparency #top .avia-builder-el-0 .container, .html_header_transparency #top .avia-builder-el-0 .slideshow_caption {
       padding-top: 0px;
    }
    #top .input-text, #top input[type="text"], #top input[type="input"], #top input[type="password"], #top input[type="email"], #top input[type="number"], #top input[type="url"], #top input[type="tel"], #top input[type="search"], #top textarea, #top select {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 39px;
    }
    .avia-slideshow li img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

## for center the box use it.

```
    .containerBox {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .containerBox-header {
        opacity: 0.9 !important;
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
    .avia_codeblock_section .avia_codeblock .widget {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

## for mobile view

```
    @media (max-width: 767px)
        #wrap_all #main #after_full_slider_1 .container .av-content-full .post-entry .entry-content-wrapper .avia_codeblock_section .avia_codeblock .widget {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .avia_codeblock_section .avia_codeblock .widget {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }

    if it's not work use !important after css like this - display: none !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and input. The CSS has helped to push the content up. I'm trying to reduce the space between the form labels so that the form can fit into the header section properly and also center it but it does not seem to work when I try to align it to the center. [link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/n3uHjgKnQvqrrvtV2fFo7g.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also realised that this may have been caused by the fact that the search box was above the moving header slider and there was a code conflict. But it’s working now. Thanks again mate